# how to eliminate a strange horizontal line in MATLAB figure that uses the 'area' function?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot a filled gaussian in `MATLAB2015` (representing the wavefunction of an electron in a Coulomb potential) using the `area` function, but an unwanted horizonal line is apearing beneath it. By the way, this line did not appear on `MATLAB2011`, but now I do not have this version of `MATLAB`.

How can I get rid of this line ??  - Please help.

The code is written below:

```
close all;clc
x1=-5:0.0001:-0.25;
x2=0.25:0.0001:5;
phi_C_1=-1./abs(x1);
phi_C_2=-1./abs(x2);

figure
plot(x1,phi_C_1,'.-k','MarkerSize',15,'LineWidth',5)
hold on
h_1=plot(x2,phi_C_2,'.-k','MarkerSize',15,'LineWidth',5);
ylim([-4 3])
xlim([-3 3])

x=-1:0.0001:1;

c1=11;c2=-2.7; 
y=0.5*exp(-c1*x.^2)+c2;
%axis off
set(gca,'visible','off')

hold on
%plot(x,y,'g.-','MarkerSize',15,'LineWidth',5)
h_2=area(x,y,c2,'FaceColor',[0 1 0],'LineStyle','none',...
    'AlignVertexCenters','off');
set(gca,'visible','off')
```

The figure that is produced is:

[image: the produced figure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `area` object's `BaseLine` that you're passing as your third input to [`area`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/area.html), which you have set as `-2.7`. Set the [`ShowBaseLine`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.area-properties.html#property_d119e40058) property to `'off'`:

```
h_2 = area(x, y, c2, 'FaceColor', [0 1 0], 'LineStyle', 'none', ...
           'AlignVertexCenters', 'off', 'ShowBaseLine', 'off');
```

[image: yay]